# Ruby Permutation (Builtin) - Result does not contain adjacent identical letters

Tags: ruby, permutation, ruby-1.8

Thank you for your help yesterday and for teaching me something new as well. :)

I have another question based on permutation... the algorithm I have works however I have the issue that identical adjacent characters are missing from the list generated.

For example, if I have the character list a-z,0-9,- and let's say that the maximum length is 2, then I should see aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff, etc. ad nauseum.

```
length = 1
alphabet = [('a'..'z').to_a, ('0'..'9').to_a, ('-').to_a].flatten
prefix = 'file-'
suffix = '.txt'


while length < 3


alphabet.permutation(length).each do |x|

@name =  prefix+x.join('').to_s+suffix
puts @name

end

length += 1

end
```

However, I am only seeing the following:

```
file-ba.txt
file-bc.txt
```

note the missing "bb" and this continues on until the program is finished.

I am sure I am missing something, just not sure what?

Comment: You can generate your alphabet like this: `[[*'a'..'z'], [*'0'..'9'], '-'].flatten`. In 1.9 you could even do `[*?a..?z, ?0..?9, '-']`.

Comment: Can I still use permutation or do I need to use another method such as repeated_permutation?

Comment: What you want is a `repeated_permutation`. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to use repeated_permutation instead of permutation.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000289

It will generate all permutations including "file-bb.txt".

Comment: That looks like it will do the job. :) I am now stuck as to why it is not liking it... test.rb:10: undefined method `repeated_permutation' for #<Array:0xb77d1f74> (NoMethodError). All I did was substitute permutation for repeated_permutation???

Comment: This method is only available in ruby 1.9 and you're probably using 1.8. Consider switching to 1.9, that's the current stable version.

Comment: Thank you. You are correct, I am using 1.8(7) on Ubuntu... switching to 1.9 is going to be a pain but worth a try. Is there a way to do this on 1.8(7) without switching to 1.9 though?

Comment: It's a ruby method, so you'll either have to upgrade or to reimplement it yourself. By the way, upgrading really isn't a massive pain if you use rvm to manage different versions.

Comment: Hi Evgeny, I am not using RVM however I am setting it up now so all that is left is to say THANK YOU for your answer and quick responses. :)

Answer (score 1):

That's [what a permutation is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation). The only 6 permutations of [1,2,3] are

```
123
132
213
231
312
321
```

Comment: Wow... I must have misunderstood the term permutation in this case as I thought that using your example, we would also have 112, 122, etc as they are also unique. Now I need to find another way of doing what I want to do? :(